# exclusion of stop words with REGEXEXTRACT in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Now I have a formula (cell D2) that extracts the surname and first name of a chess player from raw data (column A). But it doesn't fully work if there are some words in front of the last name that should not be output (blacklisted in column B). I need to add a stop-list of these words to the existing formula, so that only the last name and first name before the "long dash" sign remain. File: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IlzIbHGAe4L7ts-VeQMfkuJaRAE2ErY_pb-s-aLc5YM/edit#gid=0

> =ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A6;"[0-9]+(.+) –"));COUNTA(A2:A6);1)

[image]

Comment: the shared file has *restricted access*

Comment: Yeah, updated, man. Sorry, my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;trim(regexextract(Σ;"^\d+(?:"&textjoin("|";1;sort(B2:B;len(B2:B);))&")?(.*) –")))))
```

[image]

Comment: Unforeseen problem - if a combination of 2 words is added to the stop word list, the formula doesn't fully work. Do you have any ideas how to solve this (a7 cell https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IlzIbHGAe4L7ts-VeQMfkuJaRAE2ErY_pb-s-aLc5YM/edit#gid=0)?

Comment: if you are going to use any of these characters ***[ ] { } ( ) ^ $ | ? * + &*** within the stop words; then use the escape character as such `-rd tour 3\+2`

Answer (score 1):

##### Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A6;"[0-9]+(.+) –");COUNTA(A2:A6);1);TEXTJOIN("|";TRUE;B2:B);"")))
```

##### Result:

[image]

##### Explanation:

Using your formula you can just use `REGEXREPLACE()` to replace the characters in the string found in column B. However, the regexreplace is not accepting a range so you need to use `TEXTJOIN()` to merge all the strings in column B separated by "|" which means "or".

##### References:

Refer to the references below for more information.

- [REGEXREPLACE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)
- [TEXTJOIN()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)
- [How to Substitute More than 1 Text Using Regexreplace Google Sheets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=te5unuO0WNs)